# Loop ImageView in Android

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-volley

I am new in Android development and I closely work with MySQL databases. For the time being, I am currently working on a practice Android project, in which I'd like to loop json data convert it into bitmap -- that I did, the problem is **displaying the images** on regards to an error I keep on receiving.

I have posted my codes:

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest( Request.Method.GET, URL,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    int jsonLength = response.length();

                    // initialize new image object
                    final ImageView[] imageView = new ImageView[jsonLength];

                    // create new objects
                    imageView[jsonLength] = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

                    try{


                        // Loop through the array elements
                        for(int i=0;i<=jsonLength;i++) {

                            // setting layout
                            final LinearLayout prodLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                            prodLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                            prodLayout.setPadding(40, 20, 20, 0);


                            JSONObject jsonData = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            // get json data
                            prodImageString = jsonData.getString("image");

                            // add components to layout
                            imageView[jsonLength].setMinimumWidth(89);
                            imageView[jsonLength].setMaxWidth(91);
                            imageView[jsonLength].setMinimumHeight(89);
                            imageView[jsonLength].setMaxHeight(91);

                            final String pureBase64Encoded = prodImageString.substring(prodImageString.indexOf(",") + 1);
                            byte[] decodeString = Base64.decode (pureBase64Encoded, Base64.DEFAULT);
                            Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (decodeString, 0, decodeString.length);
                            imageView[jsonLength].setImageBitmap(decoded);

                            prodLayout.addView(imageView[jsonLength]);

                        }

                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        Toast.makeText( getApplication(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    AlertDialog.Builder add = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    add.setMessage(error.getMessage()).setCancelable(true);
                    AlertDialog alert = add.create();
                    alert.setTitle("Error!!!");
                    alert.show();
                }
            });

    // Add JsonArrayRequest to the RequestQueue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

Furthermore, I keep on receiving the following error about indexes:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: lagecy.live.desh.com.shoppincarttest, PID: 7430
              java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=37; index=37
                  at lagecy.live.desh.com.shoppincarttest.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:67)
                  at lagecy.live.desh.com.shoppincarttest.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:56)
                  at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
                  at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Sample Json Data

```
[{
    "image": "data:image/octet-stream;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAFAAUADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHAABAAIDAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUGAwQHAQII/8QARBAAAQQBAgQDBQUFBAkFAQAAAQACAwQRBSEGEjFBE1FhBxQicZEyQoGhsRUjUsHRJENichYzNFNUY6Lh8DZEdJKy8f/EABsBAQADAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAADBAUCAQYH/8QANBEAAgICAAQCCQQCAgMBAAAAAAECAwQRBRIhMUFREyJhcYGRobHRBjLB8BThIzMVUvFi/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDv6IiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAi8ymUB6i+XSNY0ueQ1o6knAULe4x4f07Is6rWDh1ax3O76NyvUm+yPG0u5OLzK59e9rujw5FOnbtEdyBG389/wAlW73tZ1qcltOlUqg9C/Mjh+g/JWIYl0+0SKeRVD90jsuVgsXqlMZs2oYAe8sgb+q4Bb4p4s1UkS6jbaw9oyIW/lhQV6vZhLZLDhKXHHMXFxz+Ksx4bZrcnorviFDkoRlts/T0FmCzH4leeOVn8Ubg4fULKCvzDpOt3tBvNs0J3wSNPxN+670c3uP/ADZd24Q41o8U1gwcsF9gzLXJ/wCpvmPzHdV78SdS2uqLNdqmWlERVSUIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiKMv8Q6RphLbupVYHDq18o5vp1RJvsCTRUu57UOG62RDNPaI/wBzEQPq7CgrXtbe8H3HSQB2fPLn8mj+anhi3T7RILcmqpbm9HUMhC4BcUu+0LieyzMU0UDT92CIZ+rslQVrUNZ1E5uX7Mo7iSY4+g2VmPDbn36FSXFsZLfMd4u6/pGng+96lVhI7OlGfp1Veue0zh2sSIpp7R/5MRx9XYXGvdo48mWwxoPZoA/Pqtew2Kcsjp+LJLzdGguz/NTrhsUtzZxDikLJKMIt+3XQ7FU9qujTzBlivbrNJ2e4Bw/HByqbqvtH1+/NIKs7acGTyshaC7Hq47/otCjwiyLVaTL9mx7jI0unmc11dkQGD9qQYPy2Km+KuC9L07TH6zRt2fci1pYyCPxgM/eLs7N9e2VFGGPCaXfZbcpyjspV3U711xdat2LB7+LIXfkUqU47jWhj5XPO3hxxnOfwBWrkcw5xsfPC6fwHxhGY49F1J7WOxyV5unMOzHHz8irk5uqO4x2VrKnd0U3H3FRrcLXrGGxaRckGw5pm8gP4uIUxV4M1F8bZHSUazHDI5XmVx8vsjHbHXrsug6lp5J5wSCCS1+Mlp7/MHuPxCjopnMkcxzPj/vItjzZ+83sc/R3o7rUfEbZL1dI4jweje5ty97ISvwbp0cUVi3etWYHEh7owIWxnycN3AZ2O+x6qYi0yjoF1ktfTKxhccNk8Pnkz5Fzsnm/XtvsdtvPE73iuedjx8bSfhkHTfPfbGT8nea2WQOiYWGPNJ7DzRzDHh/4cnbHpnbscKrO+yf7pbLtWLTV+yKRXOMOCa3E0J1bSORt/ly5oOGzj+TvXv0K5Gw3dKviRjpqtuu/Zwy1zHD9F21mraRpEsjhqrXZJJhjd4p/Ejv65375IyqvxPquka5K2eHTnttN295eQOZvkWjr+O4U1OU61yzW0XKuG25Mk4LS8/AsnA/tDh19rNP1Isg1MDDSNmT+rfJ3p9FfQdl+ZrdPwZvHgyG9fhP2Xei6x7OeMretOfpeoNdLPDHztsj77QQMO9d+vdcXUJw9LX2+xFbGePc8e3v8Ac6EiBFTOgiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIqtxJx5pHDc3u07pJ7eMmCEZLQenMTsFSrvtiuPJFHSoYx2dPIXn6DH6qaGPbNbijhziu510nC+Xvaxpc9wa0dSTgLgs/tC4o1JxZHeMQ6lteNrPz6qKsv1W+/mt23y+fizOcVahw62XdlS7iNFL1J9TvF3izQNPJFjVqrXD7rX85+jcqvXfaroFcH3dlqy4fwsDB9XEfouSNoNaQZJAAOrQNj9V9eHUiBOS4HqM7K3DhcV+5mfPjkO0I7Lrc9sVt5LaGmQM8jLIZD9G4UBc9ovFNmTkN51fIyGwwtZkfMglRscd4sJpaNZcz+JsJI/IKR0ThLW+Jon22GrHHC50fLI/leH+RGCR+K79Bi1Lro6jl5lq5ow0vefUPtG4jZVmrTW/GEsZYHujAezI6gjG6rDg0vLi93Md8kEkn1VzvaVoGg6lWrWprGoSxSct6Ng5GNBH3SN+YHBx39FatVpw8OaLFqXDNCnJXfh80z2+K4MwOVwz281w5V1tejj+74IkryLJKXpNer311ZyitUdbfhrDKc4axgzn1wOql5alypC101GeJvTmfE5o+pC6JoWtV9d0q5Bz19L1bwyDYha1mR15wf1ChdD4wtafqs2lcRWBZqPJY6VzxI1h8892ldrKsjtcvYpWYcMpqfO2n29nv67Ialw9qd7T/ANouNenQH/uLT+Vp3xt1J3W9pPBt2zO3UtK1qheNZ4JifG/w3H+EkjBB+Ska97hnRdUmAB1Km/4q5afEbW828rtjvuCP/wC644jq1tQZfbe1e/LFzeDFMWQwNyMbtb1H4LidmRbtRT17j2ivDxnubW138SY4i4crcY6R7xTrtqaxT/dvgcA0g/7t2NvVrum/kV86PUu3OHw+hAdGrQFzHwUA19uZzdiHOdjlOfPdQlvjXUJ7zLtaCCpZazw3vZl3iN8nA7HB3Hkoaa7cv3X2rEz3ySEeK5jjHkdNy0bbd8LiOHdyam9JE8uL0cyVab+hf6Wuvo1JoOJIGVNN5AyNl2z7xZmJO/O0ZyPw2WnoE1CShquncO6vP4XPzQxTxAiAHs0O3cwnY5/7nBLoeg63UF3TofGNZhjEMby3ncOjXk759e6ren1NSg1UaiWHTY63+sf4HIxje7cH7WemNyVXhUmn119i9Zkcvf6H3Hp7L9mTTtTqafpFag0GaaKINc97jt8R656+WBssVng2zVcyaGx75pjhkTwM53tHb4Qd/qtziTXIuIKdWOtWmjLXc8niEDBwRjbr16+qi45hoOmutT379Ws8hoFU87y45+LkBHw7bnruFajCahzPoim82DsVcOsvYWPS+ObOkVf2frME8r4wDE52GyFvYP5v16ryx7Q8uzV0eFuMhrppi4DPXYAKmOn069A+1S1I2/iwQ6GRrnnvkuH81giY+Y/DHGGZ3OMrxY1PL6SXYnqybrrVRXFuXl+fIstjjbiCySI7EVcH/h42g/U5Ki5pLN13PqF6az/hkkc7/ssLQGt5WjA9BhSOm6U7Ui8eKIA1vMHvYS0jO+48vx/BVJ2x7VrR9njcGrogrcuW35eH+zVErWN5Y24aOylK+kEvjGpWG02zM5oy/pv0LjjGPTOVIMj0vQqrZXl8lwvPhyDl5wNsObhxAHXBz1O4OFXbd2W1JI4gMY93MY2bNJ8yBsXeuFW7s1YTld6tK5Y+f4FqCSpZkrShofGeUhpyPw9Fp1LuoaXI9tC3YgBOT4Ly3Pz81kXrY3OcHAdFdw5NT5dbTMb9UYldmF6WU1GcOqe9b818S58Le0azHYZT15/iQu2ba5cOYf8AFjqPXsuqRyNla17HBzXDIcDkEea4A2oJQQIy44z8IzsrTwtxJZ4ekFK1zy0M/Y6uhz3b6en0U+ZgRfr09/I/P8Di7WoX9vB/k6yiwVrUNuvHPBK2SJ4y1zTkFZ1jH0iaa2giIh6EREAREQBCiIDkntU4Ve2f/SGqHOY4Btpv8JGwf8ugP4Ll4AcQF+prFeOzBJBNGJIpGlr2O6OB6hfn3i/hiXhfWnQDmdTly+tIe7f4T6hamFfzL0cvgV7Ya9ZEdoWkTarrMNOC3FVllyGPlzgnHTbuVcrXBcHDlR1viHW5H1y9rIm1Ivje4jOPi2HRUWJzmua+MvEjSCC07gjoQuw6Nr+m8VcMur617r7xGOWaOw4Na4j7Lx8/ToVNfZbBpxfT2FaVFFn/AGJb9pWdL0fhPXrAp07Gp1bbwTGZy1zX7Z/TtspDRNAuaLrtnS46NGzcMfjRX5yS2OLpkMxknOf64UNW16polt7tM4apx243FondbfM0HoS30Pmom7qOqalqZ1Czee2wdg6EcnIPJvkF0q7rdrrytePmZkrMWjTbXMn4eX16nQGy67peqOZEzV9Unb8L5bLvAqAdyANiPXKy6rxPodDUWanS1KvJZcfCs143E+OwHHXGOZp6E9RkdwubTvtXBi1btWR5SzOcPpnC+4NCdOJAK3KIuUSGQ8vLzHDc56ZXksFLrY0v7/fA9hxWPWNak/4JfivUtN1rUW26FWaKQjEz34Ak8jgd+3yUdFqmoxaf7jHcmZVySY2uwN+v4ei9n4cNSB5fcjgmY0kw8/NhwOOQ4OzvTp6r3TaGlXNO5rMlhszmPaebOQ8H4S0DYtPQ5IO6sxdcYKKW0viUJwssm7JTUW/gRpmiYAxxy7pygZK13eMbDXCI8jduUt/mpmvUYC2P4IhjqdwPp1WB+tSQ2Yqk/DEskReIorUFrwy4E7eICHDPrspbrFDW0RYMXNy5Nb9r179GNrmv7n5HYrIG5AwCRlWnStDp6pqRJicylGzmc10nO5x6YzjzUJBJc0LiienBHXY4Svcwyxc7jHn4Q3J2GO439Vy8lb5IrqcwwG4ekm9L5kroPD9fVNOumSQi23LI2ZwY9tnEddzt5bL4gfxZo7xXq6UAwncNjaWO9S4fqSpTifUIHcMftFrvdtQLwyB7DiQPBGQCOrcZKga9azq9GKTUrNmYuGeV8ruUjtsqic7ZNyfTyZpctWNCKgtvzXc84i12O1q0IpSitLFHyWZYH4D3d28w6gHIB+a1Xz+8Nb41jxQ3oZZi4j6kqYh0uCJnI2JrWdgAkuh05h/qeV3mzZWKlXWtdynk+mve+y8iEM8EZ3Pif5CtKaaSfIOWR52Y07fj5qQ1HToaB5W2Gvd/u8fEPnjZR3U5S7MrgunVmnwb9L5eZLmmuSHm+79x5EyNp3A+WMKVpaRPqILog1sLTyulOeVpxkA4BP5KLweiz1ZrEErTDLIxwOQWHBBWPbZO2XU/TsbhuPw+hxxtR82+/wAWTjNO03ThHNbe2yC4hw5umOhYAfiHnnBHkvi3xFOxpg00ugga/njcByvae+MbYPyUYIZDI4yOySck5ySfUrYh0+Sdr3QwvkDBl2BnC7hh2tba0vaYmT+oOF0S9ex2y8o9f9fUjOQuJOMknJ9VkbWceuylotNtPA5K0nKRkHlwMeeVsN0eZpHjSQwt3Jc542AODt9fnhXIYtMOs5bMHN/WOfeuXDq5F5vq/wAL6kTDWhBJlLsDf4W5J/opdumnkMkUEYiwXNmnlBBAAdnYY9Py6hfTa+lwjM1t8xIxiNhHKfP19OxWOK1WhruaKwdNnAe8kgt3ztnY9OisNdP+JNL5fg+Xnk2W2c2ZPmfnvb93j9NG0Kj2sw2R1yF2WO92y0MPw8rh2d5euML6sQwMpsbYrR1o2uIDWEGUnu4enTbfI6bgrUsatZsRPid4bWPcDhjOXAHYen9AtI5O/U9yV5DHm3uT1/fgvoRW59SXLWt78/7v6kxonEFjQrJETjNVc744jsD6jPQ/quoafqVbVKjbNWQPjd9WnyI7FcYjiknfyRRukd5MaXH8lduC9F1Wpedbna6vXLC10T+sh7HHbHmoOIUVcvPvT+5c4LmZCmquVuL+n+i+jcIiLEPrAiIgCIiAIiIAoTifQKvEWiy07GGuHxxSn+7eBsfl5+im1isf7NL/AJD+i9i2ntHjW11PzPdo2NPuyVbDTHNEcHv8iPMFeQ2JQQCebH4roWi6hpPE9V1PWqDH2qjQGzYLXPZ2ALcHOB0+iipqVJtjNGo2tF2BcXuI8yT3W/j2Sm9NaaMTiM4Vw6pS32RD1HB88fjwzOi5hz+GBzEd8Z7qQtR1Q8PqwztiaSXeOAG4HTG+fmFushHM1rG5c44A81aqvDLIInPscs0wacRA4bzY6E991LdbGtptmPRQ704xgl7fIp0bYNVmH7NrhgiG5h53Y9XOOAD658k1K3Jpwifavtkl5TGGx2A+QN64dynOPmVhj0LX9bvmPUqtqCq058FjOSNvo0dPx/FWavwr7szEOnxM8vs5/NR+lS1trXzJpYj66Tb9nRFUMV+zB/Za7Y2PH23YDsfqFsaPouqWbbanLG5p3c90ufDHcn+it+lzR0dYjpXqL4Z5wfd5JA1zXEbkAgkZx+igNabJwrqb4NHndHNqkniOk5R+6ZnAY35uJJPoAvJZTbcILqdQ4evRqU308UfGo6TqGl6hWhkreNXsSNibYh3AJOMOH3VM1tf4Yvyv0dlTNbJZzyRAscc4znc79c/opCXUben6FN4wdbmZHjme4MLs7HJx+igODtBNKkbcpY58wHLgfYA26qGUpWR3Y+3kWaqa6ZctC6vz8jaf7nwzYkdR1N8pI+Gk1olc70z2HTcrXms67q8Ilm0zS9vsNnh5ngdRjJUnb1XSaBPPYY55O7IhzH57dFGS8XRcjjWpl3bmkeG/kFB6SCe31Zr1cIzciPqQaT/viaQqCa0yXXZZnTM2jZIzliaPJvLtj0U4x1Zw+GeHHb4woKxxNauQPi8Ku1h2c3k5j+ZUUGSTENaxzyegDScrp5UGui6lmr9L5XPu6cUvr+C1WdV0+nkGbxXj7ke/59FA3Nes2MshAgZ/h+0fx/ovqDh7VLH2KMrR5vHKPzUrV4FtyYdZsxRDyYC8/wAgq8rpyN7H4fwrB9abUpLz6/QqeMnJ3PVZGRPf9lpPr2XRanB2l1xmSN9h3nI7b6BRmr8NTVszU+aaEdWdXN/qF1TXGctSeiHif6mePXvFq537emvgVVlQDd7vwb/VbAaGt5WjA8gvcHOMboeuO57Laqx66l6qPzLiXHc7iMtXz6eS6L/fxAIwvqOWWFxdFI5hxglpwtmPTLbo/FfF4EIGTNYIjYB55coF3HOkN1Fun1tMjv1GYabgkdFJI8nct7cg2xkds915bkQj6vcgxeHZF3rQ9XXj1RMSXLMu0k8rgOxcfxWHY7n81K6szTaDLp0+vNqM9HBtVvegx0LT0cQGZcNxnB2UbfHFtZhfR0TT6oby87W8k00fMQBzB7iQN+uAo1l169VfZFr/AMRkzlqyX3ZkgqWLbuWCGSU/8thcpSPhbUeTnsCGpH3dYkDcLTZS48kc+td1hkEkcTpZI/emM5GDGSQwbDfr6FaU3BLdU1KpDqHEwlkvV3S0/Ca+UScoJJcXbNH6+ijnlyfaSXzZYo4NVzamm/kl/LNyeXhujK2vJrEmoW3uDGVtOj5y5xOAOY7dV5o9mzqWsPjg4eFTT683gzWLX75weHBpaSSGjr2Bxt5r74U4Y0iHwRPSxehrw3fEle/xWP524JA+BjPIHLiAScL51XiXT9AfNJVtMvWJTM2ONsZPI8WC8gu2AYMfdyXE5JwAqcr5zbjFtm1Vw7Gq6qC+/wBzqOgmOXQ6VhsbGmWJrzyxhmc+g6KUAUZw28v4b015a1pdXY4taMAZHQDyUqsyXc0lHXQIiLw9CIiAIiIAiIgCw2f9ml/yH9FmWGz/ALLL/kd+iLuePsfn7RblljYtQk8SFsEogjusxgYwfDkHTGDsT0+Q2sOrychZcrMjdHLtI0ZHhSeWOwPUdR1wSt72dUWScPajBYhbNBLa5XxuGQRyBblnh2fTYhDUrT3dIe3kMUD2mVg6/Zd9og7gtIPmD1Ou71Vc15GTbQ8rG6d/ArDdTna4cteJxdsOuVnm4p15kpjFoRHpyPha4j67r4sVLGk3/CfzRzREPY/GD5gjyU1pR1HWRNnXJYp4vi8PwWOc5vmDjP4K1kRil6Rdv77GZXDsrcv8eyHrLp4p/dL6Glps+s6qS2ze1d+/wirEGNx6uA2U/FqNDh+u+Ke/NasOORB4pmkb/TPqcLNBoEdiMi/d1C2BsWPlcM74zyjAIUTLWn0q9NSbHDWe342GCNrRLH587t8qgpK3aT+hsX8tHLLlfXze/wDRDahq9jVdYr27Uc8Neq/nhigbl2cg5LjgZ2C+pLsd/Uve3afev2AfgE0mQwZzgNaOi3JpYXu/tFkyZ25pHuk2d0cGjbLehCtOm0XVqbG1vCjYQDz/AGi/1JXs9winv6E2PlY1k+X0KfnuT+ySKldHEWsAMGmyRQ5zyhuBnzJJWB2ga26sIppmtiBGIvGyBnvgbLoIqH+8ne/fOOn4LI2OOIEtY1vclQc8n0bNKObCp89NUYvz1t/NnP6+iaRUm8PU7NkSDBLGR8rd/Xcqw6bS4aY4mq2s5zjt4riT/wBSheIdSj1HUGiAczIm8gd3fv29Fqx6Pfkj8Q1XRxdfEmxG36uwr6xKvRqU3ys+bv8A1JxC26UIvnj7Nr7F/jrQMJMcELcjq2MDIVH4glP7cn5CW8nK0YOMYCrdr2gDhzW4qWnyQ6jG3ItYc4M5vuiN/XYZycYOe+FZjb0zVo61qOrIdV1Cv71FQda5fEAzkB3Id9jgbZwuKJRpm5Pqj3PqycyiKXR92mzyvxJqdZoaZmytHTxW5/Pqt6HifVLDuWCnHK7yZG536FQD5eJZtNit6Rw7RgEkfigPxNMW+bWvdk/g1Zab/aLZhgdJM6vHY5PBa3wYg4O3GAPTc+SmnKpvpFfF/gqU4uVCG3a9eSW/uW+GXiefDv2fXhb5ynH88rDc1X9lgu1biDTan/LiZzv+hOfyVV1PQNataf7zq3EkVerHN4dl/vLpTEenKWt6kkjb1WnX4H07SNWtRas43GR2YYWSPea8Tg8A9Rlz5N8BjfmThVpOHmvgvyaVFM5Lcub4v8EhrXFNa26p+yuHrWpWbQc2vYnYY2zkHchjd3Y8zhRnFup6voGj6dJDb90uTSyiWGvWbFyhobsTu4EEnvuCCrXrFDTtFoxVG3q1WKtVsxQxWnn94wzAkEj4iABuBu7YE4yqjc1Gn7QOLKOkiJzKDrZd7zjlmIcwAjG4aMsz3XEJua3r1UXI4sFL1YrmZSm6hZ1V5fdnllmeXFrpXl3b1UTpkXgPhl6hrmlwx5EFWzjfh+pw5r8+mUnSmCIMc2SR2XgkA9RjzUDTg6Z+yds+RU+LBWduxDk2umO33OjP410d2t6tPS0mR1i+0wGw6UtZJFtklnUOIGPwypmLivRaUt11aGeOOxCGMrx1I2CMjH2ng5f8yud16QMTs/CQMtcOxWwyK1JCC8xseRscEn6K08Cp99/Mx58Us5txaRPScWMk4p4juRwSur6hWNeMOIBjJaBk/TosA4htVzo88EUYn0us+COR+Xc4cDkkbdlCVoPdQWWHNJc4kP7Fb4o2tQHhU60kjSC6SQN+FjAfidk+Sk/x6YR3L++BDLMvss5a/HyMdO9rnFtqChqOrTt09kbySXBreRrSdwMF3TG+StuAU6ujU6kjZDYNIvikAw5nNMTj0D25z3wAO63b+oDh+S5p9F1SQGwHwuYGS4i5C3c9y7m6H1UfpNOMQz3rxc+MHD8bGSRw2A+Q3x02ws/Ikox3FaT7fk+t4Hjyyreaz9sO/v8ABf3wO58NY/0a03H/AA7P0UsonhrbhrTP/jM/RSyyWTWa53rzCIi8OAiIgCIiAIiIAscwzBIPNp/RZF8OGWEeYwh4+xQuAojFosxHV1p/5ABWd7jjLOUHJ5mHvt2VQ4Z1mtUmk0eziGbx3+G5x2eSdx6Hy81c5GEfD19e/RWspNWty8Slw+UZURUX27ld4k0k6jTY5rGizED4bubPP0+D89vVUSCaapO2aGR8UrD8LgcEHounatT99059dri172uDHDbldkEH64XMq+s0tR1kafqVGeC6+URPmrPaWueXcuSwjY564KvYN7UHCS2jK4vw5zmr6nqXj4f1maTVtQmJL7s7s9cyFa7nvkPM9xefNxz+qlb1XTKLf7DHe1iUW/c3xwObF4cm+AdicHBwR5KK1KfiilZhgpcJ14DM/kie5vvLnOwTjJdyg4HkOhVuOTUv2L7IzVwrLterJfd/b8n3FBNZdywRSSu6YY0u/RWzQKev1eWKSuRUzktmcGkD07qsxT+0WVgYRNAAwPcGxRQhrSSMkbYGx/AZWOxwtxXqeoRVL/EMdY2GZgbJcLhOcZPK1nXA6n9VFddzx03FL5lzC4cqrOZc2/dpHQb+saRpLC7UNUrQEfdLwXfTr+Spev8AtCoOaypQ0i5fkmHNEJw6NknkQ0fE8fkoThrgTTdQNdupyWny2ZJInPikbFHE9uRyguGZXbZw3YDqVbL9GWpHFcilhAr6XUrl7pxC/Ac7JMmctZtl3L8TsYGFQ/44S0nt/I3+Vzj1WkVjiXU9d0nhurcj1SKnLYsyR+BTrCH4GtG4JHOMEkHmOemFRHa7Y1CxGLj5ZjvzPklLz0PmrXxvxDpvEE8lOlG+XkuvnZbBw1zHNYDhp3Jy3qfL1UnxF7K63DOhWNWZqk9l8RaGxOia0HmIG5B9V1JqMU592e+jaS5F0OW2axGrTODtxykeowF0PT+MtJ09uhSHSpLV3Tqgjjm8QxhkmSCHDo5u4I/FUVkX9pJGT/RS0VQPBBbsQtCrGjOC5jMyc30UtLsdN0riPQ6dihb5DVdHGWzxx02vc95zlwlJyG5OcBRmo8X1HcXcO3IWzvrUYeWdnIAc77tyfUKqQC06Ih7G4b8Ic49VihglhsPfYLcPwA4dB6LtYNSe+pnridunGWixS6wyxo2qac6FzmXb/vbXk45BnIbgdT+K1NZ494htW54a0kcQcQ/EUQLo3cvLlrju0kd1rksaAB8bydmM3Lj5ABS1XT26JXoapepB8U7Zn2RMzo77LIwD97PmCltVMF1W3/fweYmVkTbe+n0NL9mP0uzq02p25Lkn7NY+clxLuaR0Z5OY9CckfLfvhb2gmsfaRp5pH+y+9YhHJyhrMOw0DyGcDKhZbFzWtQj5mRA/AwRwNIbJIGhocdzkgAD9FYeHoK0HH2ixVXmQMcWyuOCC8B24I7EYWbdJ7cfYfe8Lx414ssq165k9e7z+PgRPtUcG8eW2uxyujiz/APUKt6fBzxlncnqrr7ZNKlg4kq6kGkw2oAzm7B7O30I+irGmckPIZgQxww13kfVXMJxjUpM+Pza7rrHXWtvwXj8Cy6cNPh0ealJKynqj5AW2rdfxI+T+EbENPqQtm7oF2m21Z1S1E0V2RFzuVobyucRzfCBnG/bJwAtaCe2zldFcDg37BmiZNy/5S4Zx6LyZti5I6S3dsWXPkbI/xHjDnNBDdgOgycAbbqZ12c/NFrT/AL0Mp5FHJyWp7Xh2+ZvS6VpEN6/QmstMgqCxVnmcGRsJaCOf1OTgeQz1IWtdvQzysfpkViHnpCm6SUANazfmLN8kuyeoHXK13srwhznloc48xJ3JK1JLQnlYxznRwucA9zRkgZ3P/ZcWOFfWyW35Gpwzh+XxCWsarkh4yfl/LPinpLb+pMr0omMbkc78YY0dyf8Azdbup2YbU0dKg3w9Pqk8u+eYk7uz1Oeyy27kXgvo6U0Q08ck8wG0243337Z/HHRR4aGFsTDzHOwxt6knuVXpqlkWels7G/xLiNPCsT/DxH6+te1b7yf/AOvJeCO48Nf+mtN8vd2Y+illFcONc3hzTQ8EO93ZnPyUqsmz97OKf+uPuQREXBKEREAREQBERAF4RsvUQHM+O+FpW2pdWqRl8T95mAZ5HfxfIqL0jjTUKFdtadvvUTBhpkcQ9oxjZ2+R8/quvkA9Qq7qPBWkX5HSNidWlduXQHAJ9R0WhVlwcFXetpeJj34FsLHdiy033RAVeNqd2/VgNeSIPkDS5z2kNz8t+q5fPJ7pxqbzs+FBf55AOvKJMnHrsum6lwRDpVSS572+ZjRgsMYBwds5Hl1/BcusQOZZlLn83Oc8x81exYUylJ1dtFXJyMmqpK9dW/totVfjLQbGpWYH6TMyG1eE9uQSHD2tJ5XNb1G5BI+andM4i0HTIfCfdqNb762cNrUnxNDcHJOclx8yuWyROhDZmNy5pG3mPJZ7AsvhzHBh/wDicNlJLArl4shjxSxNNJE9V4lhkr8YRyyySTX3ctV5a4h45nEcx7DBC2mcSQR3eGrsdaWSTSKxie1xDQ9xGDjrsqlRrkQtaQQ8faB65W3MRBFgHD3/AAtHmSpf8Svu/wC9NENnELeflr6f/dm5Nx5q1m5VjoUaMV2AmCvabDzSta532Rn4Rknc4T9nTCXW28R2jO+s6tWdMXc7mMMu4Zn7OQNh5HOy3oKFLhya+yzXe+1SbCYXNk5S+YlruUefU7nsCoe1cm1bUZo68T4qs1oyiDmD3SyknBLsb4zgDp+qpWKEFutaRv8ADo3Zl0afHx9i8WzBfp16upTQ1zC6NkvhtfD0c0O2JP3j5nuV2f2mnl4CunyfF/8AsLkGp0BRsVo2zMlL+Uv5PuODsObg+RC7Xx5QfqPBGqQRN5pBD4jQO5YQ7+SoTk5OLl5n0PF4V1RrqqfaP8vr8T86VQ11nmGNwrboUWm14rTb7o2zPiIqPstcYGP/AMfLvjp6KsacA1zXuB8PO58vJWyF07Y2CGSCWEbtjnj5mgnqQQQR8s4W70cOSJ+f3OcJq6a9V+PhvyN8aBqr2xNljqhngvmY+vG3lka0ZPKWk83oOu6+otBpOl0tl28w1NR+FroDzZfnHIDuM+bugWKe5qlqHwpLkccPgmu2KvCGMZG7HMG75yQMZ64Wv7q0+Hku5ImFkTC74Y2k5IaO2T1XEYXa02kV5XYnNzJOT/vuN1zKWk0oqgmfHqNa6XzQQsJc9rchg5hsNt9yPtbqC1Ye92ZL1og3JpHSuAJLW8x6DPYDAz3WwZ4asRigY3Ynp0z3Pqt6A09MrQXpHNt6jJiSFgPMxu42I8xgg/MYVa62NfSL5pM+n4Twa6/lvyYOFS7Lxl7/ACXmzyGGLh7S22ZI3DUrDC2GJ+4Yw/ex1Dvn/XGzwRXxxZp7pD+8L3P9fsOUPOZprDrdp7fFeerjsz0A9PLsrBwMx8nFdSQNOAXkuPccp+i4hjuFU7J92mScY4ysm6GLQ9x5ltrs9dkvYvqdQ13QqfEOlS0LrMxv+Jrh9qNw6OHqFyXUeFLegHwLbPFgOzZmt+B/9D6LtwGy+ZIo5Y3RyMa9jhgtcMgqhjZUqdrun4HGZhLISafLJdmjhbNCnFeKxp9kfFnxI3HHJjO+39FoW4dVhcWTMkY7rgu7Zx+oP0XYbfBOkWXl8cclZ53/AHL8D6HIWkfZ/VJ+PULTh2yG5VqORQ3vbRJHM4lWkpVwsa8ZJN/wzlB0u94LZntYwPcA0F2XEYO/y2W3WoQ9Zy7m3wSPh9Mjrj+oXVI+BNLAHizW5QOgdJj9ApGrwto1UhzKETnDvJl/6rn0+NHsm2d38Q4zkerzRhHyX9/k5QNEl1KywUI5Z9t2xtPK3fYZO2Md1b9E9n3K9s2qOaBnPgRnOf8AM7+Q+qvzI2MaGta1rR0AGAvrAUdufZJcsei+pRq4TWpc9r5n8l8j5Y0MaGNAAAwAOwX2iKiaoREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREBC8UyNi0Gdz/s5aD8iVxG7DzPexpGQ84IOeh65XZ+NTjhiyTnHM3J8t1yBhaZi07O6t9fktvhiUa2/NnzPGvSWXKEFvS39eptDTWT6TTfpdeLULbXE3Q6VwdF/DiNpBIPnuvINIu3pIWsrBhsSPZG0Oy0cuM5J3wM7kr2relpajHfGl1p7cRJZMJjE3J7lgB+gOPRZrV7U7nuj7T42iCZ1lojyA+UuyCR5DYAfirK9MpPl+pQm8aUE5vWvBI0peG5JKtm6Zg2WnII5K7N3kF3LzHG4bnOPMAqRnZU4e1Sw2uyrZY+kIYA0skfJIR8Tidy0BxOegwAtAG4HXJDdnbLdcXWnxO5DJk5xt0HbA7LXYYo3tr0oGumeQxrY2gZPYeq8sUtbtl0LWHCWRYqsKtyl5+C9rfgamqvu2bDHXb89qQM5QZHbtHfYefn1UtXpwaBpgvWC2S1PHy1oW/3eRuXg+hx+Ix12ye51dELbeokWrD2uLIW/cfgYJB64OQewx3yo6eezqF59y7zS2Hfd7NHYegGdgqL5smfLFaij7mr/AB+C4jlbLmk+78ZP/wBY+UV4swVa7pp2vlcS9727u3J3HVfoktDgQcEHsVwGlme/Xa13O7xW/C0bD4h+a7+FzxCEYKEY+0+dwcy7Nuuvu7tr4d+i9xxbiXg13DuoTS12c2mTvLmED/V5+4f5enyUQzSbTK8lmi7LY3AOiPXfy7Fd+mhZPE6KVjXscMOa4ZBCgW8I0675HUi6DxDksPxNHy8l5DNUq1GzuuzO66L8a9zoacJfui+q+Xb+Tjc1q9C0tfC5jhnOI/L5bLWJvWmPd4U72sbzOPLhoH5ea6pqXBeo3JQGTU2wtGGjBB6YOcDyACwxcA6h4BgfcqMjJz8MZcfrtspXbCUfWs+/4LVfE54826MGCfg9Lv8A32nNatV055ZHsix3O/6eX8lJzab4FYPgLGO2BeXAudv29Mb9PRdEr+zyswg2Lsz/AEjaGf1U3S4X0iiQ6Kkxzx9+X4z+a5/yaKnuG2QZeVxbiMeTIajHyX4Xf5nLNK4V1DVXNMVdzmb5lflrNz5nr17LpXDfC0GhMMhf4tlzeUvAwGjyaFYA3AwMYXuFWvzbLly9kR4vDKqGpv1peZ6OiIipmkeYTC9RAeYXqIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIDT1WizUtLsU3nAmYW58j2P1XE9S02WvPJVsMMViF2Pl8vQru56KH1rh2lrkQE7SyZowyZn2h6eo9FcxMlVbjNbizOzcWyco30S1ZHt+DiT7FmlIyK1Fs4AtdnZwPQ5W5qOstAjjZG0OA7u6bK/XeFZ4agZ4PvYYwN/dnlc7HQY/P5qn2eHbcs7i/SLDcuJ5RASMHt0V+Fkp/sn0XmeTyOHVtPKw9yffl2l8uyKxNqMk5DXSbO+6zotipVnlAlaCxg+LxCDhozjP1Vpk4Y1C2Wtg0azFG0ENBaG4ycnfbupCjwPrDS0hsNYdcySc3bHQZXMoQ/dZYtl+P6mnVB04GLyR93/z6lRtxyRW3SO57E8jnF07t8kHBIA6/Vee6WLT2x5cSQMMYMuJwM7d99l0+vwIyTkdqOoSzhowGRgMaPT/zCsVDR9P0xuKdWOI93AZcfmTuvHn11R5YLZh2YOXmW+lyJa9/V/he4pnCPBk1azFe1CLwhFgxxH7Tj2LvLHXC6EEHRerMuundLmka+NjQx4ckAiIoiwEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBMIiA8wEwF6iA8wEwF6iAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiA//9k="
}]
```

Comment: Problem is here `imageView[jsonLength] = new ImageView(getApplicationContext())` you are directly accessing the element which do not exceeds the current size , you must loop through an array and create new create object for each element not just single one.

Comment: // Loop through the array elements
for(int i=0;i<jsonLength;i++) // remove =

Comment: And also change loop as @BrianHoang said in his comment

Answer (score 0):

```
 // create new objects
// as per comment this use Activity context
                imageView[jsonLength] = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

                try{

// i<=jsonLength change to i<=jsonLength-1
                    // Loop through the array elements
                    for(int i=0;i<=jsonLength;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a single object of `ImageView` in `imageView[]` on index which exceeds the current size of an Array on this line

`imageView[jsonLength] = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());`

That is cause of crash and instead of creating a single object you should loop for that like

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < imageView.length; i++){
   imageView[i] = new ImageView(getContext()); // here you should use Activity context here
}
```

and change loop as Brian suggested in his comment

```
for(int i=0;i<=jsonLength;i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonLength;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

For future problems relating to this solution, I wrote the following code; though it does not do what I really need, but it can be helpful.

```
// declarations 
LinearLayout secondLinearLayout;
ImageView[] imageView


// in --> onCreate that is overridden
secondLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
secondLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
secondLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
secondLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


// --> this is when I call volley
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {

        JSONObject jsonData = response.getJSONObject(i);
        prodImageString = jsonData.getString("image");

        imageView[i] = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());

        decodeImageString(prodImageString, imageView, i);
        imageView[i].setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView[i].setId(i);

        imageView[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), v.getId() + "",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        // add to parent layout
        secondLinearLayout.addView(imageView[i]);
        secondLinearLayout.addView(textViews[i]);

    }

    relativeLayout.addView(secondLinearLayout);
    scroll.addView(relativeLayout);
    //secondLinearLayout.addView(scroll);

    setContentView(relativeLayout);


} catch (JSONException e) {
    AlertDialog.Builder add = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    add.setMessage(e.getMessage()).setCancelable(true);
    AlertDialog alert = add.create();
    alert.setTitle("Error!!!");
    alert.show();
}


// method used to set image_view
private void decodeImageString(String imageString, ImageView[] imageView, int count){

final String pureBase64Encoded = imageString.substring(imageString.indexOf(",") + 1);

byte[] decodeString = Base64.decode (pureBase64Encoded, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (decodeString, 0, decodeString.length);
imageView[count].setImageBitmap(decoded);

}
```